# twisted cubic at a point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

I've been working on this problem for the better part of a day and can't for the life of me figure it all out.

Given $r(t) = \langle t, t^2, t^3 \rangle$ at $P(2,4,8)$.  Find the curvature, $N(t), T(t), B(t)$, Torsion and the equation of the osculating plane.

We know that this is a twisted cubic in $R^3$ and I'm fairly sure I found the curvature ($k$).  My problem is finding the normal vector since it requires a derivative and the magnitude of said derivative.  I calculated the derivative but algebraically it's way too long. Obviously if $r(t) = \langle t, t^2, t^3 \rangle$ and the point is $(2,4,8)$ then $t=2$.

Who can help solve this problem? I feel like I'm missing something here. 
Thank you all.

Comment: Please use mathjax I cant understand what the curve is.

Comment: Take your expression for $N$ and substitute the numbers in as soon as possible. $B$is then just the cross product of $T$ and $N$.

Answer (score 1):

If $r(t)=(t,t^2,t^3)$ so $r'(t)=(1,2t,3t^2)$ and $|r'(t)|=\sqrt{1+4t^2+9t^4}$. So $$T(t)=\frac{(1,2t,3t^2)}{\sqrt{1+4t^2+9t^4}}$$ At that point $P=(2,4,8)$ we have $r'(t)=(1,4,12)$ and $|r'(t)|=\sqrt{161}$, so $$T(t)|_{P}=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{161}}, \frac{4}{\sqrt{161}},\frac{12}{\sqrt{161}}\right)$$. By the same way, do for $N=\frac{T'(t)}{|T'(t)|}$ and then for $B=T\times N$.

Comment: I got this far but the problem is with N. The derivative seems way too much to calculate. Then taking the magnitude is even more trouble.

Comment: Right. But why don't find a normal vector to $T$ by guessing it. For example $\left(\frac{4}{\sqrt{161}}, \frac{2}{\sqrt{161}},\frac{-1}{\sqrt{161}}\right)$. Take this one as a normal to $T$ and now make it unit.